# PromiseKit 6 error in cannot convert error

Tags: swift, alamofire, promisekit

Firstly, I'm aware that the implementation has changed in v6 and and I using the `seal` object as intended, the problem I'm having is that even when following the example to the letter it still gives me the old `Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> CustomerLoginResponse' to expected argument type '(_) -> _'` error.

Here is my function that returns the promise:

```
 static func makeCustomerLoginRequest(userName: String, password: String) -> Promise<CustomerLoginResponse>
{
    return Promise
        { seal in
            Alamofire.request(ApiProvider.buildUrl(), method: .post, parameters: ApiObjectFactory.Requests.createCustomerLoginRequest(userName: userName, password: password).toXML(), encoding: XMLEncoding.default, headers: Constants.Header)
                     .responseXMLObject { (resp: DataResponse<CustomerLoginResponse>) in
                if let error =  resp.error
                {
                    seal.reject(error)
                }
                guard let Xml = resp.result.value else {
                    return seal.reject(ApiError.credentialError)
                }
                seal.fulfill(Xml)
            }
    }
}
```

and here is the function that is consuming it:

```
static func Login(userName: String, password: String) {
    ApiClient.makeCustomerLoginRequest(userName: userName, password: password).then { data -> CustomerLoginResponse  in

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to provide more information if you want to chain more than one `promises`. In `v6`, you need to use `.done` if you don't want to continue the promises chain. If you have only one `promise` with this request then below is the correct implementation.

```
static func Login(userName: String, password: String) {
    ApiClient.makeCustomerLoginRequest(userName: userName, password: password)
         .done { loginResponse in
              print(loginResponse)
         }.catch { error in
              print(error)
         }
}
```

Remember, you have to return a `promise` if you are using `.then` until you break the chain by using `.done`. If you want to chain multiple `promises` then your syntax should look like this,

```
ApiClient.makeCustomerLoginRequest(userName: userName, password: password)
       .then { loginResponse -> Promise<CustomerLoginResponse> in
             return .value(loginResponse)
        }.then { loginResponse -> Promise<Bool> in
             print(loginResponse)
             return .value(true)
        }.then { bool -> Promise<String> in
             print(bool)
             return .value("hello world")
        }.then { string -> Promise<Int> in
             print(string)
             return .value(100)
        }.done { int in
             print(int)
        }.catch { error in
             print(error)
        }
```